# 'du -hs *' on Mac failing with "du: illegal option -- n"

Tags: macos, command-line

I want a list of all the sub-directories and their total sizes. I can do it with the `du -hs *` command in CentOS and Ubuntu, but why doesn't it work on Mac?

This is the output I get:

```
MyMac:~ user$ du -hs *  
du: illegal option -- n   
usage: du [-H | -L | -P] [-a | -s | -d depth] [-c] [-h | -k | -m | -g] [-x] [-I mask] [file ...]
```

As far as I know, `*` is a wildcard. Does macOS not support wildcards?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between "du -sh \*" and "du -sh ./\*"?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/110750). With GNU `du` (Ubuntu), you may prefer `du -hd1` which will include hidden ones, skip non-directory files, also give the disk usage for `.` and work even if the list of files in the current directory is very large.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You probably have a file whose name begins with `-n`:

```
MyMac:~ user$ du -hs *
4.9G    Applications
1.1G    Desktop
2.2G    Documents
954M    Downloads
3.3G    Library
2.4M    Movies
7.8G    Music
 29G    Pictures
1.9G    Public
MyMac:~ user$ touch ./-none
MyMac:~ user$ du -hs *
du: illegal option -- n
```

Try `du -hs -- *`.